# Automate the Standard logicapp using Azure Devops pipeline/How to create standard type Logic Apps using ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-server-2019

Can someone pls help me to automate build and release pipelines for Standard logicapp in Azure DevOps.

I can create consumption type logic apps with sample workflow using ARM templates. I want to create standard type logic apps with sample workflows using ARM templates.

But, I’m unable to find any reference documentations for the above one.

please, can anyone help me out on this one.

Comment: I gave you information on your other question. Refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. Please use the below commands to create Standard type Logic Apps using ARM template.

**PowerShell**

```
$projectName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a project name to use for generating resource names"
$location = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the location, such as 'eastus'"
$templateUri = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.logic/logic-app-create/azuredeploy.json

$resourceGroupName = "${projectName}rg"

New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location "$location"
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateUri $templateUri

Read-Host -Prompt "Press [ENTER] to continue ..."
```

**CLI:**

```
read -p "Enter a project name name to use for generating resource names:" projectName &&
read -p "Enter the location, such as 'eastus':" location &&
templateUri=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.logic/logic-app-create/azuredeploy.json &&
resourceGroupName="${projectName}rg" &&
az group create --name $resourceGroupName --location "$location" &&
az deployment group create --resource-group $resourceGroupName --template-uri  $templateUri &&
echo "Press [ENTER] to continue ..." &&
read
```